# Admin Observer Data after Add item to Order from Quote

Tags: magento-1.9

admin Observer i want to get items subtotal i tried the below event on that i am getting only quote Id rest not able to get rest quote Data i checked in database quote Table data is there 
can you please help me to find out how to do that or let me know the Correct observer Event name

```
sales_quote_item_set_product
sales_quote_add_item
sales_quote_product_add_after
adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data
```

Observer.php

```
public function testQuote($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
    mage::log($quote->getData(),null,'observer.log');
}
```

Log data:

```
[entity_id] => 12121
    [store_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2017-07-26 03:42:25
    [updated_at] => 2017-07-26 03:42:25
    [converted_at] => 
    [is_active] => 0
    [is_virtual] => 0
    [is_multi_shipping] => 0
    [items_count] => 0
    [items_qty] => 0.0000
    [orig_order_id] => 0
    [store_to_base_rate] => 1.0000
    [store_to_quote_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_currency_code] => USD
    [store_currency_code] => USD
    [quote_currency_code] => USD
    [grand_total] => 0.0000
    [base_grand_total] => 0.0000
    [checkout_method] =>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in admin panel or in frontend?

Comment: @john : Admin panel

Comment: Have you tried `mage::log(var_export($quote->getData()),null,'observer.log');` ?